# How to write a select statement that outputs all key values in all rows

Tags: hive, hiveql

My hive table has a map of none or many key value pairs. I don't even know most of the keys. I want to write a select statement that outputs all key values in all rows.

something like

```
select t.additional_fields[*] 
   from mytable as t
```

Comment: you should consider posting sample data,the expected output and your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

[`map_keys(map<K,V>)`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-CollectionFunctions) returns array of all keys, you can explode it. The following query will return all distinct keys:

```
select
       s.key
    from
        (
         select m.key
           from mytable t
                lateral view explode(map_keys(t.additional_fields)) m as key
         ) s
group by s.key
```